# Как очистить всю ветку от файлов?

Tags: git, github

Работаю с репозиторием на github.

Вчера я прочитал про непрерывную интеграцию и статью на хабре, как проводить это с Android-приложениями. Для этого мне нужна пустая ветка autobuild. Однако коварный Github клонировал master-ветку со всеми файлами.

Удалять по одному при помощи интерфейса очень запарно и засоряет историю. По-другому я хотел сделать, но, если честно, не понял, как не просто проигнорировать файлы, а удалить и из интернетов, и из моего рабочего места.

Comment: `коварный Github клонировал master-ветку со всеми файлами` — вы что-то здесь напутали. На GitHub появляются коммиты и ветки, которые вы туда сами запушили из своего локального репозитория командой `git push`.

Comment: К сожалению, я забыл тогда про консоль и сделал новую ветку через сайт.

Comment: ну гит тоже скопирует состояние коммита от которого ветвишься. Это базовый функционал гита, а не коварный гитхаб

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вам нужна просто пустая ветка в проекте, сделать это можно так

```
git checkout --orphan <branchname>
```

Comment: Т.е. пуллнуть репозиторий и исполнить эту команду?

Comment: Да, а потом запушить все в репозиторий

Comment: Все, понял, огромное спасибо. Пошёл удалять ветку с гитхаба и создавать через консоль.

Comment: Удачи, обращайся ;)